# Efficient method to put several items into value field

Tags: pivot, powerpivot

I need to create several pivot table once and week, and I wonder if there is any efficient method to drag several item into value field. (I tried to left click on the item I need, but it will automatically go to "row" field.)

And also, is there any efficient method to set up "value field setting"?
I want to summarize value field by "sum", but it will automaticall become "count". If i have 20 items in "value field", I need to click value field setting for 20 times...

Comment: Stacy, could you please post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have used the PowerPivot tag then I will assume that you are talking about a PowerPivot PivtotTable not a standard Pivot.

The first thing to do is explicitly create measures (called Calculated fields in 2013) for each calculation you wish to make - not only does this mean you can choose to `sum` not `count` but also that you can specify the format you want and once it has compiled, the measure will be added more quickly that just dragging the column into the box.

The easiest way to create a measure is to right click on the table and then in the dialogue box add a formula such as:

`=SUM('mytable'[mycolumn])`

In the same dialogue you can name the measure and choose the number format.

Once you have the measures you need, you can create a 'set' which is simply a collection of measures/dimensions. The easiest way to do this is create the Pivot you want then go to:

`PivotTable Tools>Options>Fields, Items & Sets>Create Set based on....`

From there you can name the set and make alterations. Then in future you will see that set in the field list and be able to add it to you pivots with a single click.

Jacob